# CanvasText on jquery flot not show extended ascii characters

Tags: jquery, canvas, flot

I'm using jquery flot with canvasText (from jquery flot text) to show legend, this allows me to convert to pdf using tcpdf, but in this canvasText don't appear characters that aren't in ASCII-127 like "á","º",etc...

When I try to show "Temperatures in ºC", it only shows "Temperatures in C"...

I see that there is a declaration (CanvasTextFunctions.letters) where there are all standard ascii letters but I don't know how I can add other letters...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What canvas text plugin are you using, exactly?  The official jquery.flot.canvas.js (https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/jquery.flot.canvas.js) does not contain a list of ASCII letters.  What version of Flot are you using?

Comment: @togarha, I believe you are using this: http://www.lessaworld.com/projects/flotCanvasText/, that's speaks to flot 0.6, time to upgrade...

Comment: I'm using 0.6 version of flot, surely the best way is to update this version to lastest one, but this is a project that must be as minimum modified as possible, then, is not a possibility in that moment because I don't know if the update can break any other part of the web...

Comment: Looking at the plugin, it "draws" the text using a mapping provided for each letter.  Since your character isn't in the mapping it just skips it.

Comment: I finally understand how to add new letters, then I will answer my question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I understand how to add new letters to the table, this is some of them:

```
    'º': { width: 12, points: [[8,21],[10,19],[10,17],[9,15],[7,14],[5,14],[3,16],[3,18],[4,20],[6,21],[8,21],[10,20]] },
    'á': { width: 19, points: [[9,19],[15,24],[-1,-1],[15,14],[15,0],[-1,-1],[15,11],[13,13],[11,14],[8,14],[6,13],[4,11],[3,8],[3,6],[4,3],[6,1],[8,0],[11,0],[13,1],[15,3]] },
    'à': { width: 19, points: [[9,19],[3,24],[-1,-1],[15,14],[15,0],[-1,-1],[15,11],[13,13],[11,14],[8,14],[6,13],[4,11],[3,8],[3,6],[4,3],[6,1],[8,0],[11,0],[13,1],[15,3]] },
    'é': { width: 18, points: [[9,19],[15,24],[-1,-1],[3,8],[15,8],[15,10],[14,12],[13,13],[11,14],[8,14],[6,13],[4,11],[3,8],[3,6],[4,3],[6,1],[8,0],[11,0],[13,1],[15,3]] },
    'è': { width: 18, points: [[9,19],[3,24],[-1,-1],[3,8],[15,8],[15,10],[14,12],[13,13],[11,14],[8,14],[6,13],[4,11],[3,8],[3,6],[4,3],[6,1],[8,0],[11,0],[13,1],[15,3]] },
    'ó': { width: 19, points: [[9,19],[15,24],[-1,-1],[8,14],[6,13],[4,11],[3,8],[3,6],[4,3],[6,1],[8,0],[11,0],[13,1],[15,3],[16,6],[16,8],[15,11],[13,13],[11,14],[8,14]] },
    'ò': { width: 19, points: [[9,19],[3,24],[-1,-1],[8,14],[6,13],[4,11],[3,8],[3,6],[4,3],[6,1],[8,0],[11,0],[13,1],[15,3],[16,6],[16,8],[15,11],[13,13],[11,14],[8,14]] },
    'ú': { width: 19, points: [[9,18],[15,23],[-1,-1],[4,14],[4,4],[5,1],[7,0],[10,0],[12,1],[15,4],[-1,-1],[15,14],[15,0]] },
    'ù': { width: 19, points: [[9,18],[3,23],[-1,-1],[4,14],[4,4],[5,1],[7,0],[10,0],[12,1],[15,4],[-1,-1],[15,14],[15,0]] },
    'ì': { width: 10, points: [[8,17],[3,23],[-1,-1],[5,14],[5,0]] },
    'í': { width: 10, points: [[3,17],[8,23],[-1,-1],[4,14],[4,0]] }
```

Comment: So, what's the secret to the mapping?

Comment: It draws the letters, it takes the width you mark and a heigh of about 25px. you mark the coordinate points between the line must go. the coordinate [-1,-1] makes a break and it starts a new draw in the next coordinate...